# asp.net mvc4 jquery get value from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have asp.net mvc4 project where I'm use an ajax query to get data from my server side

```
$.getJSON('/Administrator/GetStudentAppNumbers/', function(data) {
        //alert(data[0]);
        $.each(data, function (i, appNumber) {
            var program = $('"#' + appNumber + '"').html();
            var newProgram = $.trim(program).replace(/\s/g, " ");
            var shortText = $.trim(newProgram).substr(0, 40) + "...";
            $('"#' + appNumber + '"').html(shortText);
            $('"#' + appNumber + '"').click(function () {
                alert(newProgram);
            });
        });
    });
```

But when I try to invoke it in console, they return me an error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#UZ43"

And when I try to invoke it from `alert(appNumber);` they return me `UZ43`.

Have any ideas where I mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, so you are trying to call `html()` on a string; hence the error. Try this:

```
var program = $('#' + appNumber).html(); // note the removed double quotes (")
```

Answer (score 2):

The double quotes shouldn't be part of the value of the selector:

```
$('"#' + appNumber + '"')
```

Should be:

```
$('#' + appNumber)
```

With `$("#UZ43")`, the *value* of the selector is `#UZ43`.

With `$('"#' + appNumber + '"')`, the *value* is `"#UZ43"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
 $('"#' + appNumber + '"').html(shortText);
```

with

```
 $('#' + appNumber).html(shortText);
```